# Single user account per email domain-name

Tags: customer-account

Recently I came along a simple idea to prevent multiple users of the same company. A lot of our customers use their company email address when they try to create an account. Almost none of them use Gmail or Hotmail. So to prevent multiple accounts per domain, I would like to build a check which queries the database for " LIKE %domeinname.com% " (or something like that).

I've been searching on the interwebs for some information but couldn’t find any which can help me realize this feature. I'm a PHP developer with not much know-how of Magento. This is the reason why I would like to receive basic information on how to build or start with this extra check inside the registration process.

Comment: you means if a customer have abc@gmail.com and abc@yahoo.com then you want abc@yahoo.com cannot register at your site? am i right?

Comment: No, I mean when a user tries to create an account on for example abc@mycompany.com and later on some other employee of the same company tries to create an account with def@mycompany.com, it will get an error that someone already made an account on this domain-name. Excluding domain-names like gmail.com, outlook.com, hotmail.com etc. from this check ofcourse.

Comment: @Wimbjorno Personally I see this as a bad idea I am not sure why you would limit user registration to your website but the answer from Marius should work for you

Answer (score 1):

Magento already prevents 2 accounts with the same e-mail.
All you need to do is to change that behavior not to allow the same domain.
The verification is done in `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer::_beforeSave()` by this code:

```
    $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
    $bind    = array('email' => $customer->getEmail());

    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from($this->getEntityTable(), array($this->getEntityIdField()))
        ->where('email = :email');
    if ($customer->getSharingConfig()->isWebsiteScope()) {
        $bind['website_id'] = (int)$customer->getWebsiteId();
        $select->where('website_id = :website_id');
    }
    if ($customer->getId()) {
        $bind['entity_id'] = (int)$customer->getId();
        $select->where('entity_id != :entity_id');
    }

    $result = $adapter->fetchOne($select, $bind);
    if ($result) {
        throw Mage::exception(
            'Mage_Customer', Mage::helper('customer')->__('This customer email already exists'),
            Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS
        );
    }
```

You need to change:

```
$bind    = array('email' => $customer->getEmail());
```

to this

```
$parts = explode('@', $customer->getEmail());
$bind    = array('email' => '@'.$parts[1]);
```

and this

```
->where('email = :email');
```

to this:

```
->where('email like CONCAT("%", :email)');
```